# Crash [UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] after dispatch_main_queue_callback

Tags: ios, stack-trace

we're receiving a specific crash report plenty of times, but i cannot figure out where this crash comes from. It seems to me, that its triggered by a callback to the main queue, but i cannot figure our what this could be.

Here's the stack-trace:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3b9315b6 objc_msgSend + 22
1   UIKit                               0x35aaeab3 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 159
2   UIKit                               0x35b238ef -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 51
3   QuartzCore                          0x35858c01 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 209
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3bd4d4b7 _dispatch_client_callout + 23
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3bd4edcb _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 227
6   CoreFoundation                      0x33c64f3b __CFRunLoopRun + 1291
7   CoreFoundation                      0x33bd7ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
8   CoreFoundation                      0x33bd7d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
9   GraphicsServices                    0x3779b2eb GSEventRunModal + 75
10  UIKit                               0x35aed301 UIApplicationMain + 1121
11  myapp                               0x000e5b03 main (main.m:14)
```

Any idea, i could hunt this down?

Comment: Did you try setting an exception breakpoint?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the crash on development devices, it appears on some users devices i have no access to.

Answer (score 3):

The delegate for some animation has deallocated. Use the Zombie instrument to detect which one.

Comment: Any idea, how i could narrow down the animation, there are a lot of the in the app?

Comment: Use the Zombie tool in Instruments. Look for animation delegates that may deallocate before the animation is done, slow animations.